# MySQLdb Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: python, mysql, wamp, mysql-python

I have python 2.7 installed.
I have wamp running.
I have MySQL running on 10127 port.
I have root set up with no password
i have (unrelated) php code running that connects fine with the call
    mysql_connect('localhost:10127', 'root', '');

when i try from the command line:

```
mysql -u 'root' -p '' -h 'localhost:10127'
```

i get the error

> Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:10127'

Similarly, when i make the call

```
   import MySQLdb as mdb
    import sys
    con = mdb.connect('localhost:10127', 'root','', 'dbname')
```

i get the error

> Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:10127' (11004)"

Does anyone know why-oh-why?

Comment: the MySQLdb problem was fixed by calling MySQLdb.connect(port=10127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI expects:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost --port 10127
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql -u 'root' -p '' -h localhost -p 10127

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: mysql -u 'root' -P '' -h localhost -p10127